# firebase admin with node.js: update in nested JSON tree

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, iso

I use the below code on my Node.js admin server to retrieve data from my JSON tree, which works fine and prints the content of all snapshot2's to the console.

```
ref.once("value", function(snapshot0) {
  snapshot0.forEach( function(snapshot1) {      
    snapshot1.child("Food").forEach( function(snapshot2) {                                                                                                                                                  
      console.log(snapshot2.val());
    });    
  });                         
});
```

However, how can I edit the data held at snapshot2?

If I try to call e.g.

```
snapshot2.update({250:42})
```

then it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: snapshot2.update is not a function
```

I am really confused and think this must be a problem many people have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update a snapshot. but you can update a reference, and you can get reference from snapshot by doing

```
 snapshot.ref
```

, then you can do this to update

```
snapshot.ref.update({250:42})
```